# Customize `sliderInput()` appearance

Tags: r, shiny

I want to use sliders as "likert-type questions" when using shiny as a survey tool.
Therefore I want to customize the caption of the ends of the slider to somewhat like "I totaly aggree" and "I totally disagree".
Is there a smooth way for doing that?

Comment: talking about likert-type, this: https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-radio/ comes to mind,...maybe that would fit even better?

Comment: Yes - good hint - I will use it, when asking a lot of likertquestions. Thank's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do you want something like this? Make sure to adjust your `width` accordingly

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput('slider', 
              label = div(style='width:500px;', 
                          div(style='float:left;', 'I totally disagree'), 
                          div(style='float:right;', 'I totaly aggree')), min = 0, max = 10, value = 7, width = '500px')

)

server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes - That's it! Thank's

Comment: Great answer! One follow-up question. If the slider is included inside a column(4,) indentation, how could we change the style from a fixed width of 500px to a width of 100% ?

Comment: @Angelo, you can simply remove it or add `style='width:100%;`

Comment: Sorry, I wonder if you could also help me with the following. If we look at your solution above, we basically have the label on the left hand side and on the right hand side. However, it's kind of missing the actual subject. Would it be possible to also have a central label that says for example "Did you like the movie"?

Comment: @Angelo, by default, no as per https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp, however you can write your custom one as per https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-elements-float-to-center/#:~:text=The%20CSS%20float%20property%20is,float%20center%20in%20CSS%20layout.